# Regex get a value after a delimiter

Tags: regex

I was trying to write some regex to be able to fetch the value of banana. So given this list of text.

So essentially, for each line, I would like to be able to get whatever comes after `banana=` and have it stop at `|` if it exists.

```
apple=1|banana=2.5|oranges=1
banana=2.5|apple=1|oranges=1
apple=1|oranges=1|banana=2.5
apple=1|oranges=1|banana=-2.5
banana=2.5
```

I got as far as writing `(?i)banana=(.*)` but of course it gets everything after the exact match.

Do you guys have any solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to be able to get whatever comes after `banana=` and have it stop at `|` if it exists.

You may use a negated character class instead of a greedy dot pattern:

```
(?i)banana=([^|]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7yfCPz/1)

The greedy dot, `.*`, matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars (in NFA engines) as many as possible (usually, up to the end of the line).

If you use `[^|]`, a negated character class, it will match any char but `|`.

**Pattern details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `banana=` -  a literal substring (prepend with `\b` to match it as a whole word)
- `([^|]*)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than `|` (to avoid empty matches, replace `*` with `+` quantifier).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. Also, that regex101 site seems very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Done! Thank you again :)